# Which stage in C/C++ compilation process makes it system-dependend?

Tags: c++, c, compilation

Am going through [this](https://www.joshwieder.net/2014/11/compiling-c-using-clang.html) tutorial. Is only the linking stage that makes the compilation of c/c++ code system dependent? Isn't assembly language code generation also system dependent? Isn't system, machine and processor the same thing in this context?

Comment: Everything involved in compiling and linking programs is system-dependent. The standard just describes the language, not how you compile and execute it.

Comment: @Barmer Is ABI being used in the linking stage? Or from the Compilation stage?

Comment: I think it's involved in both.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain how "Linking is very system-dependent"

Comment: The format of object files is specified by the ABI. The command for invoking the linker, and its parameters, are implementation-dependent.

Comment: Read the C specification, you won't find anything about how to compile or link programs in there. It just describes the program source code.

Comment: Clang does not translate directly to assembly but instead makes system-agnostic LLVM byte codes as middle step and then translates that to assembly.

Comment: This conversation is very informative Thank you both. @ÖöTiib, Can the intermediate byte code be produced as a file (say with some switch)?

Comment: You should read "5.1.1 Translation environment" of the standard. It doesn't exactly tell when things become system dependent but it describes a number pf phases for the compilation.

Comment: @Barmar The standard actual have some info about translation phases (N1570 - 5. Environment)

Comment: @SomOneElse yes you can get *.ll files out of clang, it is -emit-llvm

Comment: @4386427   The standard describes phases of translation.    It doesn't describe how those phases are implemented.   The net effect is *as if* the translation phases are executed in required order, but the standard doesn't specify how any parts of the toolchain (compiler, linker, etc) work, how programs are run, or what the host operating system does in that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean this bit:

> Linking is very system-dependent, so the easiest way to link object files together is to call clang on all of the different files that you wish to link together.

What they mean is that the *command-line syntax* of linking is very system-dependent. You may have to tell the linker explicitly what standard library files should be included, for instance, which varies across platforms. But on all platforms, the clang frontend knows how to invoke the linker correctly. The tutorial is advising you to link via clang instead of invoking the linker directly.

This is certainly not the only system-dependent part of compilation, but other parts are better hidden. Passing a flag like `-O2` to clang enables all sorts of CPU-dependent program transformations, but you don't have to tell clang on the command line how to do them.

Comment: `-O2` does not enable CPU specific optimizations, `-march` does. The `-O` flags only optimize within the features of the specific arch being selected from the supported target platforms. And the default arch is not `-march=native`, but the common denominator.

Comment: @Ext3h I meant that the default architecture may be x86, x64, ARM, PowerPC... and the same flag works for all of them.